# Bootstrap conditionally Placeholder on Label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline form with several inputs.

In larger devices, I wanna use '**label**' to indicate field type, but in smaller ones,

I wanna use '**placeholder**' to save space. For 'label' I can use bootstrap classes d-none and d-sm-block.

How can I conditionally show 'placeholder' for smaller devices?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <label class="control-label d-none d-sm-block mr-2" for="id1">Country</label>
    <input type="text" id="id1" placeholder="input country">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no harm in showing placeholder on larger devices as well. Placeholder will appear on small and larger devices by default. If you still want this - you need to do this with jQuery or Javascript to have your placeholder hidden on larger devices and shown on small devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in my opinion, **there is no reason to hide the placeholder in any device. Because it exists to create interactive controls for input elements**. But in any case, if you insist to remove it in any device you can use [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) pseudo-element like this:

```css
input::placeholder {
   color: transparent;
}
```

To make your placeholder disappear.

So for a more precise example of it, you can see the snippet below, where I defined my media for devices with a maximum width of `767px` you can change it to whatever you want.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit browsers */
    color: transparent;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: transparent;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: transparent;
  }
  input::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <label class="control-label d-none d-sm-block mr-2" for="id1">Country</label>
    <input type="text" id="id1" placeholder="input country">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```